# how to Graphql + Reactjs | invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

so i am a newbie on Graphql and i'm trying understand how it works.
before using Graph, i was used to return the Html at the end of the project
now, as i understood i have to return it in every function (?) so for example for my toDo app i need to create a GetTask where i return all the Html ?
it is not really clear on my mind.

lemme show you my code; i am hiding all the function because none of them works at the moment since i have to do all the query from the beginning

```
import './App.css';
import Task from './Task';
import React from 'react';
import TaskForm from './TaskForm';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {useQuery,gql,useMutation} from '@apollo/client'

const GET_TASKS = gql`
  query GetTasks {
    tasks {
      name
      done
    }
  }
`;

const ADD_TASK = gql`
mutation AddTask($name: String!) {
  addTask(name: $name, done: false) {
    name
    done
    id
  }
}
`;

function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(() => {
    const storedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    return storedTasks ?? [];
    //return storedTasks !== null ? storedTasks : [];
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
  }, [tasks]);

  function GetTasks(){
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_TASKS); 
  
    if (loading) return 'Loading...';
    if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
  
    return (
      <main>
        <h1>{numberComplete}/{numberTotal} Complete</h1>
        <h2>{getMessage()}</h2>
        <TaskForm onAdd={AddTask} />
        {tasks.map((task, index) => (
          <Task
            {...task}
            key={index}
            onRename={newName => renameTasks(index, newName)}
            onTrash={() => removeTask(index)}
            onToggle={done => updateTaskDone(index, done)}
          />
        ))}
      </main>
    );
  }

  function AddTask (name) {
    const [addTaskMutation, { data, loading, error }]  = useMutation(ADD_TASK);
    let input
    if (loading) return 'Submitting...';
    if (error) return `Submission error! ${error.message}`;
    return (
      <main>
        <h1>{numberComplete}/{numberTotal} Complete</h1>
        <h2>{getMessage()}</h2>
        <TaskForm onAdd={e=>{ 
        e.preventDefault();
        addTaskMutation({variables:{name:input.value}})
        input.value = '';
        }} 
        />
        {tasks.map((task, index) => (
          <Task
            {...task}
            key={index}
            onRename={newName => renameTasks(index, newName)}
            onTrash={() => removeTask(index)}
            onToggle={done => updateTaskDone(index, done)}
          />
        ))}
      </main>
    );
  }
  
  function removeTask(indexToRemove) {
  }
  
  function updateTaskDone(taskIndex, newDone) {
  
  }
  
  function getMessage() {
    const percentage = numberTotal === 0 ? 0 : (numberComplete / numberTotal) * 100;
    if (percentage === 0) {
      return 'no tasks complete ';
    }
    if (percentage === 100) {
      return 'nice job! ';
    }
    return 'keep it up! ';
  }

  function renameTasks(index, newName) {
  }

  const numberComplete = tasks.filter(t => t.done).length;
  const numberTotal = tasks.length;

}

export default App;
```

is this how should i send my html ? in the GetTasks function? ofc it won't show anything until i am not calling the function.

here there is another example of how i was showing my html before

```
import './App.css';
import Task from './Task';
import React from 'react';
import TaskForm from './TaskForm';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {useQuery,gql,useMutation} from '@apollo/client'

const ADD_TASK = gql`
mutation AddTask($name: String!) {
  addTask(name: $name, done: false) {
    name
    done
    id
  }
}
`;

function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(() => {
    const storedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    return storedTasks ?? [];
    //return storedTasks !== null ? storedTasks : [];
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
  }, [tasks]);

 function AddTask (name) {
    const [addTaskMutation, { data, loading, error }]  = useMutation(ADD_TASK);
    let input
    if (loading) return 'Submitting...';
    if (error) return `Submission error! ${error.message}`;
    return (
      <main>
        <h1>{numberComplete}/{numberTotal} Complete</h1>
        <h2>{getMessage()}</h2>
        <TaskForm onAdd={e=>{ 
        e.preventDefault();
        addTaskMutation({variables:{name:input.value}})
        input.value = '';
        }} 
        />
        {tasks.map((task, index) => (
          <Task
            {...task}
            key={index}
            onRename={newName => renameTasks(index, newName)}
            onTrash={() => removeTask(index)}
            onToggle={done => updateTaskDone(index, done)}
          />
        ))}
      </main>
    );
  }
  
  function removeTask(indexToRemove) {
}
  
  function updateTaskDone(taskIndex, newDone) {
}
  
  function getMessage() {
    const percentage = numberTotal === 0 ? 0 : (numberComplete / numberTotal) * 100;
    if (percentage === 0) {
      return 'no tasks complete ';
    }
    if (percentage === 100) {
      return 'nice job! ';
    }
    return 'keep it up! ';
  }

  function renameTasks(index, newName) {
  }

  const numberComplete = tasks.filter(t => t.done).length;
  const numberTotal = tasks.length;
    

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>{numberComplete}/{numberTotal} Complete</h1>
      <h2>{getMessage()}</h2>
      <TaskForm onAdd={AddTask} />
      {tasks.map((task, index) => (
        <Task
          {...task}
          key={index}
          onRename={newName => renameTasks(index, newName)}
          onTrash={() => removeTask(index)}
          onToggle={done => updateTaskDone(index, done)}
        />
      ))}
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

so how should i return my site ??
now another problem is that when i click on the button to add the task i get
invalid hook call
i m desperate :D